# Looping issue: BeautifulSoup only collecting some elements per page

Tags: python, selenium, loops, beautifulsoup

I'm crawling through multiple pages to collect some HTML, but it seems that BeautifulSoup is only collecting some random selection of information. I'm also using selenium with geckodriver on Ubuntu 16.04 OS to click through to the next page.

```py
# import libraries
import urllib.request
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import certifi
import urllib3
import pandas as pd 
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
import requests

# This URL is ok according to eBay's robots.txt:
urlpage = 'https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_nkw=lululemon&_sacat=15724&rt=nc&LH_Sold=1&LH_Complete=1&_pgn=6'

http = urllib3.PoolManager(cert_reqs='CERT_REQUIRED', ca_certs=certifi.where())
r = http.request('GET', urlpage)
page = urllib.request.urlopen(urlpage).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

# Specify containers
item_containers = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 's-item__info clearfix'})
print(len(item_containers)) # should be about 4 dozen

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

# get web page
driver.get(urlpage)

# Loop through
for container in item_containers:
    # If the item has a summary, then extract...:
        if container.find('h3', class_ = 's-item__title s-item__title--has-tags') is not None:
        # The summary
            summary = container.find('h3', class_ = 's-item__title s-item__title--has-tags').text
            summaries.append(summary)
        # The color
            #color = container.find('span', {'class': 's-item__dynamic s-item__dynamicAttributes2'})
            #colors.append(color)
        # The price
            price = container.find('span', attrs = {'class':'POSITIVE'}).text
            prices.append(price)

            button = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('x-pagination__control')[1]
            button.click()

            driver.refresh()
            time.sleep(20)

        # driver.quit()
```

There are ~4 dozen elements to collect for each tag I specify per page, but after several pages, I'll only have maybe a dozen. Loop logic is off- please advise, I'm trying to improve my python!

Comment: Added, apologies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that without selenium.Use requests of Beautiful Soup.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
url="https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_nkw=lululemon&_sacat=15724&rt=nc&LH_Sold=1&LH_Complete=1&_pgn=6"
html=requests.get(url).text
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
summery=[]
price=[]
for item in soup.select('div.s-item__info.clearfix'):
    if item.select_one("h3.s-item__title"):
        summery.append(item.select_one("h3.s-item__title").text)
    if item.select_one("span.s-item__price"):
       price.append(item.select_one("span.s-item__price").text)

print(summery)
print(price)
```

---

For pagination you can use while loop ans use the page_number how many page you are after.for example i have provided upto 10 pages.

```
page_num=1
baseurl="https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_nkw=lululemon&_sacat=15724&rt=nc&LH_Sold=1&LH_Complete=1&_pgn={}"

summery = []
price = []
while page_num<=10:
    html = requests.get(baseurl.format(page_num)).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

    for item in soup.select('div.s-item__info.clearfix'):
        if item.select_one("h3.s-item__title"):
            summery.append(item.select_one("h3.s-item__title").text)
        if item.select_one("span.s-item__price"):
            price.append(item.select_one("span.s-item__price").text)

    page_num=page_num+1

print(summery)
print(price)
```

Comment: Oh, this is *much* appreciated, thank you. I had an inkling that bs4 could paginate for me, this is so, so much nicer than the weird bugs selenium has been throwing at me. I'm passing this on to my team since we're all working on something similar right now, so your knowledge will be disseminated even further. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is picking up the advertisements:

`item_containers = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 's-item__info clearfix'})`

The div tag "s-item__info clearfix" is also used for the advertisements shown in the left pane.

Comment: I noticed- but not only the ads, it also picks up the posted items...right? But only some of them...note that I am extremely new to scraping, so it's a hot mess of collected items, I know..

Comment: The products might be nested further. .findAll() wont traverse other containers if they are aren't within the current container, it stops at the first and picks up all of the tags, hence having both ads and actual products.